# How to get extream x,y coordinates for hough line peaks with skimage

Tags: python, hough-transform, scikit-image

```
h, theta, d = transform.hough_line(outlines)
for acum, angle, dist in zip(*transform.hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0 = (dist - 0 * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    y1 = (dist - outlines.shape[1] * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    x0 = ...
    x1 = ...
    rr,cc,_ = draw.line_aa(x0,y0,x1,y1)
```

What I want is the `x0` and `x1` values between the range of my outline shape, that is 640,640 (2D). And I want to scale the `y0` and `y1` to the size of my `outline.shape`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your situation a little more in detail?

Comment: Ok. So imagine if you have a square boundary image. And with hough transform, you get the lines. Now with a formula I found over web, I get y coordinates of the lines. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html
Now these line boundaries have no limit. By no limit I mean the point could be less than 0.
All I want is by some equation I get the x coordinates along with ys and that too in a range of 0 to 640.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y0, y1` coordinate that you calculate with that formula correspond to where the line intersects the edges of your image. That is why it includes `0` and `outlines.shape[1]`.

`y0` corresponds to the row where the line intersects column 0, hence `0 * cos(angle)`.

`y1` corresponds to the row where the line intersects the last column of your image, i.e. its width (which is `outlines.shape[1]`)

So you can draw a line from `(0, y0)` to `(width, y1)` to emphasize the detected lines. Use, for example `outlines[line(0, y0, width-1, y1] = 1`. Note I put `width - 1` because indexing starts from 0 and `width` is out of bounds. This is not the case in your formula because it is subtracted from `dist`

[This tutorial](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html) illustrates well how it works and how to add the discovered lines to your image (in the first part). Replace the uninspired X-shaped image with an image of your choice and you will see the lines. Your image should ideally be binarised and have not too many points, so try passing it through and edge detector (Canny) or a skeletonization procedure.